# Is there a 'NOT IN' comparator in DynamoDB using query or scan

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I read this document
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

maybe no condition equivalent `not in` of RDB just only exists `in` condition.

How can I implement `not in` or is there an equivalent to `not in`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here an implementation In PHP

```
public function getRecordsByInExpression($tableName, $providerCode, $fieldName, $values, $logicalOp = self::IN_EXP)
{
    $queryExp =[
        'TableName' => $tableName,
        'KeyConditionExpression' => 'ProviderCode = :pc',
        'FilterExpression' => $logicalOp == self::IN_EXP ? "$fieldName IN (:list)" : "NOT ($fieldName IN (:list))",
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
            ':pc' => $providerCode,
            ':list' => implode(',', $values)
        ]
    ];

    return $this->query($queryExp)->get('Items');
}
```

At the end a NOT IN = NOT (field IN (:list))